# SQL Server T-SQL: trouble grouping data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table `ListofString` with these columns:

```
parent_id
parent_prop_id
element_value
```

My data looks like this (I've excluded the bulk for simplicity)

```
parent_id   parent_prop_id  element_value
------------------------------------------
C4236016    BEAE885B        acw1
C4236016    BEAE885B        acw2
C4236016    BEAE885B        acw3
C4236016    BEAE885B        acw11
C4236016    1DC045A5        mmw1
C4236016    1DC045A5        mmw2
C4236016    1DC045A5        mmw3
```

In a select, I'd like to get this:

```
parent_id   String1         String2
------------------------------------------------
C4236016    mmw1|mmw2|mmw3  acw1|acw2|acw3|acw11
```

Instead I get this:

```
parent_id   String1         String2
------------------------------------------------
C4236016                    acw1|acw2|acw3|acw11
C4236016    mmw1|mmw2|mmw3
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    LOS0.parent_id,
    String1 = CASE 
                 WHEN LOS0.parent_prop_id = '1DC045A5' 
                    THEN STUFF((SELECT '|' + LOS1.element_value 
                                FROM ListOfString LOS1
                                WHERE LOS0.parent_prop_id = LOS1.parent_prop_id
                                ORDER BY LOS0.parent_prop_id
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')
                    ELSE '' 
              END,
    String2 = CASE 
                 WHEN LOS0.parent_prop_id = 'BEAE885B' 
                    THEN STUFF((SELECT '|' + LOS1.element_value 
                                FROM ListOfString LOS1
                                WHERE LOS0.parent_prop_id = LOS1.parent_prop_id
                                ORDER BY LOS0.parent_prop_id
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')
                    ELSE '' 
               END
FROM 
    ListOfString LOS0
GROUP BY 
    LOS0.parent_id, LOS0.parent_prop_id
```

Any ideas how I can include these two rows into the same line?
If I remove that group by of parent_prop_id, I get the message:
Column 'ListOfString.parent_prop_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks

Sorry if I didn't format this correctly.

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your current solution just slightly, all you need is another level of aggregation. If you remove the `else` clause from the `case expression` you can further group by your `parent_id` and remove the nulls by aggregating `string1` and `string2`

```
select parent_id, Max(String1) String1, Max(String2) String2 from (
    select LOS0.parent_id,
    case LOS0.parent_prop_id
        when '1DC045A5' then 
            Stuff((
            select '|' + LOS1.element_value 
            from ListOfString LOS1
            where LOS0.parent_prop_id = LOS1.parent_prop_id
            order by LOS0.parent_prop_id
            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
        end as String1,
    case LOS0.parent_prop_id
        when 'BEAE885B' then 
            Stuff((
            select '|' + LOS1.element_value 
            from ListOfString LOS1
            where LOS0.parent_prop_id = LOS1.parent_prop_id
            order by LOS0.parent_prop_id
            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
    end as String2
    from ListOfString LOS0
)los
group by parent_id
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5da7df098763284ed7ea33d3d6d3b527)

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of SQL Server, you would use `string_agg()`.  Oh, wait.  SQL Server does support that yet.

But you can emulate it with conditional aggregation:

```
select parent_id,
       string_agg(case when seqnum_p = 1 then parent_prop_id end, '|'),
       string_agg(case when seqnum_e = 1 then element_value end, '|')
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parent_id, parent_prop_id order by  parent_prop_id) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by parent_id, element_value order by element_value) as seqnum_e
      from t
     ) t
group by parent_id;
```